# Update SQL Server database using Excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, excel, interop

What I want to do is import a bunch of rows from a database into Excel (this part is already implemented and working), then edit that data within Excel, and then update the rows in the database on a button click, which should appear in the last cell of each row.

Is this possible to do? I'm using VS 2008 C# and Excel interop v14 at the moment. The database server is SQL Server.

Comment: "Build a house out of cheese" -- equally possible as what you're asking, but perhaps not advisable.

Comment: I know it sounds unsavory.. :D But that's the requirement :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without reference to the many, many problems you will encounter:

```
''Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library

Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cn.Open ServerCon

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "insert_user"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters("@username").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)
cmd.Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Access with a datasheet. What you're asking for is possible, but requires extensive fiddling.

If you insist on Excel look into the query add-in tool (Excel 2003 or earlier) or the Data ribbon (Excel 2007 or later).